# Expanding range of data (for PCA)

Tags: pca, logarithm, range

I am interested in computing 5 indices of structural connectivity between 116 different brain regions, and their associations with behavioural performance. I plan on using prinicipal component analysis (PCA) on these structural connectivity measures to find components (i.e., connectivity profiles) capturing maximal variance.

My concern is that 4 out of 5 of my structural connectivity measures have extremely limited range (this is the nature of the indices that I am working with; nothing to do with the data acquisition quality). For example, the range for 4 of these measures is .0005 to .0015. Even when I z-score this data relative to the group mean, the majority of values cluster between .2-.6 z-score. I'm concerned that the nature of the data is such that there is just not enough variance and dynamic range that can be picked up by the PCA, or that any correlations will be severely underestimated.

Are there any methods (e.g., logarithmic expansions) that I can use to expand/increase the dynamic range of this data or any suggestions on alternate approaches to handling such data with extremely limited range?

Comment: What are the units? For instance, if you’re measuring in meters and find the numbers to be too small for your liking, maybe measure in nanometers and get numbers a billion times larger.

Comment: For most of them, its mm2/sec - that's millimeter (squared)/second

Comment: Why not measure in $\mu m^2/s?$ Your data have the same interpretation, but the numbers will be bigger.

Comment: Re "Even when I z-score this data relative to the group mean, the majority of values cluster between .2-.6 z-score."  If true, this implies you have some large outlying data.  That's a concern for PCA, especially with such a small dataset, because just one or two observations might control all the results.  What does the scatterplot matrix of the data reveal?